# C++ CLI for each command not found

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling, generic-collections

I'm creating a C++/CLI project to wrap native C++ DLLs using Visual Studio 2017.

For wrapping generic collections I found a great library on GitHub https://github.com/goldshtn/marshalfx which looks promising, but it does not compile using VS 2017:

I get the error:

```
Error   C2760   syntax error: unexpected token 'for each', expected 'statement'
```

here: [link](https://github.com/goldshtn/marshalfx/blob/842d534acb3b38ab0c84d4fe6afdbbabe612d118/MarshalFx/marshal_fx_details.h#L148)

Which is strange, as it is apparently the documented way in C++/CLI to iterate over IEnumerables.

Trying to replicate the issue, it seems it also doesn't work with very simple examples like the MSDN example below:

[MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx)

So, question is, what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to include something, maybe set some compiler options, or, rewrite the indicated line in the marshal_fx library to get it working?

Comment: Such are the hazards of templates, if you don't use them correctly then you can get pretty hard-to-diagnose compile error messages.  We can't see how you tried to use it.

Comment: @HansPassant Even if I remove the template completely from the project and use the example provided by Microsoft in the linked MSDN page, I get syntax errors for the "for each" command. However, the message is different, it is expecting a '(' at the position of the "each", it's like the "for each" command is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @HansPassant Created a new Console app project, set CLR support in project properties (/clr), using the following code: https://pastebin.com/VyydApgD the problem is present.